# How do i align multiple elements in mat-card-content angular css html

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, styling

i am trying to  right-align and center the button vertically within the mat-card-content, but it is not working properly and if i try to add more divs or change my html it looks even worse or does not align properly. My title should be left-aligned and also vertically centered as it is right now.

[image: this is what it currently looks like]

(I used ugly background-colors to understand what it does whenever I change something)

```
<div>
  <div *ngFor ="let recipe of cookbook">
    <mat-card class="recipe">
      <mat-card-content class="title"> {{recipe.title}}
        <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" class="more">
          <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
          <button mat-menu-item>
            <span>Edit</span>
          </button>
          <button mat-menu-item>
            <span>Delete</span>
          </button>
        </mat-menu>
        </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
  </div>
</div>

.recipe {
width : 400px;
height: fit-content;
background-color: #d4d4d4;
padding: 15px;
margin: 15px;
border-radius:4px;
}

.more {
right:-20%;
background-color: red;
}

.title{
  background-color: green;
  text-align: left;
}
```

The only thing I tried that somewhat worked how i wanted was using right: for my .more button in my css but it is not consistent depending on how long my title is or at some point exceeds the mat-card

Any other ideas on how I could fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you are trying to do with flex

Try something like this

I also made a quick Stackblitz too https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mvecpg

You might want to have a read of the custom theming https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components

```css
.recipe {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 400px;
}

.recipe__card {
  background-color: #d4d4d4;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -2px #ccc;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.recipe__card-content {
  padding-bottom: 0 !important;
  padding-top: 0 !important;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 4px 8px;
}

.recipe__title {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.recipe__more-btn {
  background: red;
  border: none;
  margin: 8px;
}
```

```html
<section class="recipe" *ngFor="let recipe of cookbook">
  <mat-card class="recipe__card">
    <mat-card-content class="recipe__card-content">
      <span class="recipe__title">{{recipe.title}}</span>
      <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" class="recipe__more-btn">
          <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
        </button>
      <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
        <button mat-menu-item>
            <span>Edit</span>
          </button>
        <button mat-menu-item>
            <span>Delete</span>
          </button>
      </mat-menu>
    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
</section>
```